# How can i send lots of post request very very fast in python?

Tags: python, post, request

This is my code for sending lots of POST request in python language.it works correctly.But this is so so slow.i think because it send POST request one by one.
i have to question:
1.how can i make this code in a way that it send POST request very faster?
2.how can i send a POST request without waiting for its response?

```
import sys
import json
import requests
import time
url = "http://club.raakdarou.com/users/main/GettingGift"
number=2237499999938616
headers={'Host': 'club.raakdarou.com',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0',
'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'Referer': 'http://club.raakdarou.com/users/main',
'Content-Length': '53',
'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=4sirmg5n05fkszmvbasr4vnt; __RequestVerificationToken=AsWNgNzLVjU8kCNvWvTjn_tJiBlEKE5NH_xO-o7eGkq3h3av7I1e0_qu6NO80SNKfiV-c5Ajm6nlrDE7pFcKFkdr6ZHVX9zXAWYZt79c_pw1',
'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
def sendRequest(number):
    try:
        while(number>=2237400000000000):
            data = {'gift': number , 'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'}
            r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
            print(number)
            number=number-1

    except:
        print ("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        sendRequest(number+1)
```

Comment: use multi-threading function

Comment: https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests

Comment: You can just make that `data=data` as `requests` will automatically convert `dict`s as needed. You can make concurrent/async requests (using what Ashwini has pointed out) but you'll need to be careful to not get yourself rate limited/blocked.